# How to send a function pointer using Unmanaged Exports from C++ to C# dll to be used as callback

Tags: c#, c++, interop, function-pointers

I am using Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports to call functions in my C# managed dll from my native C++ application. I now need to somehow pass a function pointer from my C++ application to the C# dll so that my dll can do a callback into c++. This has got me stumped.

C++

```
//Normal call to CSharp dll using Unmanaged Exports
FString UHostBridgeComponent::DoCallToCCsharp()
{

  FString filePath = FPaths::Combine(*FPaths::GamePluginsDir(), TEXT("ThirdParty"), TEXT("CSharp.dll")); 

  void *DLLHandle = NULL;
  if (FPaths::FileExists(filePath))
  {
    DLLHandle = FPlatformProcess::GetDllHandle(*filePath); // Retrieve the DLL.
  }
  if (DLLHandle != NULL)
  {
    _DoTest DLLFuncPtr = NULL;
    FString procName = "DoTest";
    DLLFuncPtr = (_DoTest)FPlatformProcess::GetDllExport(DLLHandle, *procName);
    if (DLLFuncPtr != NULL)
    {
        const char* result = DLLFuncPtr(false);
        FString output(result);
        return output;
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

C#

```
    //Function called from C++ application
    [DllExport("DoTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static string DoTest(bool result)
    {

        //Do processing
        //...

        string result = "this is the result string";
        return result;
    }
```

I would imagine that I need to pass a pointer to a function in C++  when calling a function in C#.

```
const char * result = DLLFuncPtr(pointerToMyFunction);
```

That pointer must be saved to a variable in C# and executed as callback when the C# dll wants to send data to the c++ application.

I am unsure how to define these functions and variables. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself. See below the answer

C++

```
//Function pointer typedef
typedef bool(*functionPointer)(const char* data);

//the actual function that gets pointed to
bool UHostBridgeComponent::realFunction(const char * data)
{
    FString output(data);
    UE_LOG(LogEGM, Log, TEXT("CALLBACK FUNCTION data= %s"), *output);   
    return true;
}

//function pointer as variable (not yet pointing to realFunction)
functionPointer myFunc;

//function to call in C# that passes the function pointer
typedef bool(*_DoSendCallbackFunction)(functionPointer callback);

bool UHostBridgeComponent::DoCallbackTest()
{
    FString filePath = FPaths::Combine(*FPaths::GamePluginsDir(), TEXT("ThirdParty"), TEXT("CSharp.dll")); 

    void *DLLHandle = NULL;
    if (FPaths::FileExists(filePath))
    {
        DLLHandle = FPlatformProcess::GetDllHandle(*filePath);
    }
    if (DLLHandle != NULL)
    {       
        _DoSendCallbackFunction DLLFuncPtr = NULL;
        FString procName = "DoSendCallbackFunction";
        DLLFuncPtr = (_DoSendCallbackFunction)FPlatformProcess::GetDllExport(DLLHandle, *procName);
        if (DLLFuncPtr != NULL)
        {
          myFunc = &realFunction; //point myFunc to the function realFunction
          return DLLFuncPtr(myFunc);            
        }
    }
  return false;
}
```

C#

```
public delegate bool FooDelegate(string data);

    [DllExport("DoSendCallbackFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static bool DoSendCallbackFunction(IntPtr callback)
    {
        FooDelegate myFooDelegate = (FooDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(callback,typeof(FooDelegate));
        string theString = "This is the data!!";
        myFooDelegate(theString);

        return true;
    }
```

and the result is printed to my log file:

```
LogEGM: CALLBACK FUNCTION data= This is the data!!
```